Angular Distribution Function for Clustered Data Points
I was tasked recently with analyzing a cluster of individual points (each point representing a particulate), and I was advised that it would be good to apply an angular distribution function (ADF) on the cluster to analyze the orientation of the cluster.
However, I don't really know much about the ADF, and I'm aiming to code an implementation of it in python. What exactly is an ADF, and what would an algorithm for it look like?
All the resources I've found online pertaining to the ADF relates to quantum or molecular dynamics, and I have no idea how to dissect those. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_distribution_function and maybe https://auto-fox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/1_rdf.html
